# Spring-framework CVE

Tags: spring-mvc, wso2-api-manager, cve

I need to bypass a spring-web framework vulnerability identified in spring-web-5.3.25.jar available in the wso2am-apim in lib/runtimes/cxf3/spring-web-5.3.25.jar.

The CVE Info is:
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/cve-2016-1000027

I've tried to move springframework forward to version 6.0.12 (by replacing the jar files) without any success.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24434#issuecomment-744519525

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to upgrade the spring version to 6.x versions of WSO2 API Manager since spring 6.x versions are only compatible with [JDK versions upwards of JDK 17](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range).

Since the current released versions of APIM support JDK 8/11, it is not possible to simply upgrade the spring dependencies due to compatibility issues with other dependencies.